# How to log from parachain's validate_block function

Tags: parachain, debugging, logging

I would like to investigate and debug the way my parachain runtime's `validate_block` function is executing. As a first attempt I've [placed some log lines](https://github.com/Off-Narrative-Labs/Tuxedo/blob/10d075192c0faeb017873be2ed99c70936dc5d55/tuxedo-core/src/validate_block/implementation.rs#L86) in my `validate_block` implementation.

The `validate_block` function is part of the parachain protocol and not the normal Substrate block execution flow. It is only run by the relay chain validators, not the collators. So I would only expect to see my logs appearing on the validator nodes. But **the validators do not print the logs in the parachain runtime**.

It occurs to me that in production a validator would not want to see logs from any random parachain runtime, so I wouldn't be surprised if this is suppressed. **Is there any way to make the validator node print the parachain runtime's log messages?**

I'm looking for solutions at any level of complexity from adding cli flags (which would be ideal) to hacking Polkadot to expose the necessary host functions.

Comment: @bkchr commented [on github](https://github.com/Off-Narrative-Labs/Tuxedo/pull/130#issuecomment-1774929876) to add `sp_runtime::runtime_logger::RuntimeLogger::init()` which I've tried. It compiles, but still validators print no logs.

Comment: Temporary workaround: put panics like `panic!("executing else branch")`, and the validator will print them. But it also immediately stops executing, so you have to re-compile and re-launch the chains to get the next debugging step.